# Outlook 2010 : is it possible to *keep* conversations open?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

My workplace has just upgraded all Outlook 2007 clients to 2010 (I think).

Unfortunately this has changed the way conversations work.  I made productive use of the conversations view in the previous version, but now, conversations *always* collapses as soon as the focus is changed.

So I can no longer look at the screen to see which conversations have been responded to by whom (granted a little number updates the number of unread messages).  Also when scrolling through with the keyboard it makes the messages dance around as conversations expand and collapse wildly!

I've searched on the net and most answers suggest that keeping conversations expanded is impossible in 2010.  Does anyone know a workaround or plugin that would revert the apperiance back to Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this behavior by modifying your view settings.

In Outlook:

- View Settings:

  - Group By: Conversation(ascending)

    - Sort items by:  Conversation (ascending)

      - then by: Received (Descending)

Source: a comment in the discussion thread on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-keep-conversations-open-in-outlook-2010/f956bca6-b471-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

Comment: This works (tried in Outlook 2013). Unfortunately Outlook then shows even single messages as a "conversation" which really clutters the screen.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/783469/904401