# How to get all messages expanded in conversation mode in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

When selecting `Show as conversation` view mode in Outlook 2013

[image]

There are 3 display modes as below snapshots i.e.

1. Collapsed mode
2. Expanded mode #1 - my response mails (i.e. the ones in `Sent box`) not displayed
3. Expanded mode #2 - my response mails are displayed

I just want mode #2 to be the only one to display my messages. How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/390095/outlook-2010-is-it-possible-to-keep-conversations-open

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just check *Always Expand Selected Conversation* in *Conversation Settings* menu

(right below *Show as Conversations* check).

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you asked—I didn't even know about the "Conversation Settings" menu.

Comment: This setting appears to be applied per folder - how do I apply it globally?

Comment: @eric did you ever figure out how to apply this globally?

Comment: This also doesn't automatically expand all until the conversation is selected. Sometimes you want to see them all expanded, for example, to see which conversations are hot ones, similar to eudora, opera mail, thunderbird, pretty much every other desktop email client has this functionality!

Answer (score 2):

After checking *Always Expand Selected Conversation* in the *Conversation Settings* menu, click the *Change View* menu item and choose *Apply Current View to Other Mail Folders...* to apply the Conversation Settings to all folders.

[Outlook - Change View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8dr2.jpg)