# How to Always Expand Conversations outlook 2013 (not just those "selected")

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I want to do the same thing as showed in this link explaining microsoft outlook 2010. There is a superuser question similar to this, but the answer explains how to "always expand selected conversation" and I want them expanded even when NOT selected.

http://blogs.office.com/2010/03/05/customizing-your-conversations-experience-plus-video/#comments

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook 2010 : is it possible to \*keep\* conversations open?](https://superuser.com/questions/390095/outlook-2010-is-it-possible-to-keep-conversations-open)

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by turning off the official *Conversation mode*, and in view settings:

- Group By: Conversation (ascending), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S24GV.png)
- Sort by: Conversation (ascending), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1L55.png)
- Then Sort by: Received (descending)

This way you basically get conversation mode (tho it looks a bit different), and it's always expanded.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is not possible because it is a bad idea to expand every conversation by default.

The only Conversation Settings are listed below:

[image]

Comment: Please explain why it should be a bad idea. It was there in Outlook 2010 and people are used to it.

Comment: Matter of opinion. Explain why it is a good idea. Because it existed in 2010 doesn't mean it should continue to exist.